# css3 linear-gradient not working in Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox

The following CSS3 transition does not work in Mozilla Firefox

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #b8d2e0, #FFFFFF);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #b8d2e0, #FFFFFF);
```

It is working on Chrome, Safari (iOS) though

Comment: Use `-moz-linear-gradient`.

Comment: aah.. that worked.. damn how could i miss that.. thanks @Mash

Comment: Here is a website to generate blurs, box shadows, etc for all browsers. http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `-moz-linear-gradient` or [Mozilla Documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) may help you better